# HTML Submit button vs AJAX based Post (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, design-patterns, submit

I'm after some design advice.

I'm working on an application with a fellow developer. I'm from the Webforms world and he's done a lot with jQuery and AJAX stuff. We're collaborating on a new ASP.MVC 1.0 app.

He's done some pretty amazing stuff that I'm just getting my head around, and used some 3rd party tools etc. for datagrids etc.

but...

He rarely uses Submit buttons whereas I use them most of the time. He uses a button but then attaches Javascript to it that calls an MVC action which returns a JSON object. He then parses the object to update the datagrid. I'm not sure how he deals with server-side validation - I think he adds a message property to the JSON object. A sample scenario would be to "Save" a new record that then gets added to the gridview.

The user doesn't see a postback as such, so he uses jQuery to disable the UI whilst the controller action is running.

TBH, it looks pretty cool.

However, the way I'd do it would be to use a Submit button to postback, let the ModelBinder populate a typed model class, parse that in my controller Action method, update the model (and apply any validation against the model), update it with the new record, then send it back to be rendered by the View. Unlike him, I don't return a JSON object, I let the View (and datagrid) bind to the new model data.

Both solutions "work" but we're obviously taking the application down different paths so one of us has to re-work our code... and we don't mind whose has to be done.

What I'd prefer though is that we adopt the "industry-standard" way of doing this. I'm unsure as to whether my WebForms background is influencing the fact that his way just "doesn't feel right", in that a "submit" is meant to submit data to the server.

Any advice at all please - many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both solutions are viable, though using submit buttons will make your application more accessible (i.e. JavaScript will not be required in order to use it).

You could also do the both - start with a page that has all the necessary logic using postbacks, and "upgrade" it with nice AJAX-y requests and animations. This way, users with JavaScript will get the eye candy, and the page will *gracefully degrade* when when a user without JavaScript visits the page, falling back to the postback mechanism.

Answer (score 5):

The thing you need to take into consideration is how the application will work if javascript is not available. You should strive to ensure that the basic functionality works without it. This is called progressive enhancement or unobtrusive javascript and is considered a best practice.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement

The way you should do it is to use a form with a real submit button and then hijack that form to use ajax if the User Agent supports it. This is usually pretty trivial to do using the jquery forms plugin. In your action method, you can check to see if the incoming request is an ajax request by checking the Request.IsAjaxRequest property. This is set by MVC automatically on requests that have the X-Requested-With header set to XMLHttpRequest. Then you would return a full view or just some json based on that.

Here's a short screencast demonstrating this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQsFR1rkgMU&feature=player_embedded

Comment: +1. Except for the kind of complex apps that can *only* be done with JavaScript, you should get it working without JS first, then adding the whizz-bang on top.

Comment: Thanks. I've thought about this too but the app is an internal application developed for a customer. Javascript is allowed.